# Simple set-theoretic property to extract a subsequence in infinitely many steps

Tags: co.combinatorics

Well, I know that I'm going to have some vote-down, because this should be a very simple property but the real story is that... I am not able to prove it!

For any fixed $n\in\mathbb N$, I have a finite partition of the natural numbers

$$
\mathbb N=A_1^n\cup...\cup A_{k(n)}^n
$$

(every set of the partition is infinite). Suppose that the sequence $k(n)$ is bounded. I want to make a choice of a set $A_{i_n}^n$ for each partition such that $A=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_{i_n}^n$ is infinite.

Intuitively this should be possible, and I have a sketch of the proof making use of the upper density on natural numbers, but I don't think it is completely right and anyway it sounds a bit too complicated.

Motivation: I am basically extracting infinite subsequences from a sequence and I want to be sure to find, at the end of the story, a subsequence.

Comment: What if the $n$th partition splits the naturals into ten pieces based on the $n$th digit of the decimal expansion?

Comment: To sharpen Clinton Conley's remark: take $k(n)=2$ for each $n$, and look at the binary expansion of each natural number...

Comment: @Clinton Conley - why not post that as an answer, so the question can be put to bed?

Comment: On the other hand, judging from your motivation, what you probably what to do is take a free ultrafilter $U$ on $\mathbb{N}$ and choose your $i_n$ such that $A_{i_n}\in U$. The $A_{i_n}$ can then be diagonalized to choose your subsequence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As requested, here's the comment posted as an answer:

What if the $n$th partition splits the naturals into ten pieces based on the $n$th digit of the decimal expansion?

(Of course ten is chosen for familiarity and not for optimality.)

---

Apologies for such an extensive edit, but I couldn't visualize this either, and this doesn't fit into a comment. Using binary (and indexing from 0) instead of base 10 gives:
  $$A_0^0 = evens, A_1^0 = odds$$
  $$A_0^1 = (0\bmod 4)\cup(1\bmod 4), A_2^1 = (2\bmod 4)\cup(3\bmod 4)$$
  $$A_0^n = \{ n \in {\mathbb N} \colon 0\leq n\bmod 2^{n+1} <2^n\},
    A_1^n = \{ n \in {\mathbb N} \colon 2^n\leq n\bmod 2^{n+1} <2^{n+1}\},$$ 
But now $$\bigcap_{i=0}^n A_{i_n}^n$$ is a single congruence class modulo $2^{n+1}$ for any choice of $i_n$, and the second positive element of a congruence class must be at least as large as the modulus, and the modulus goes to infinity, so the infinite intersection cannot have two elements.

Comment: Sorry, but maybe I don't understand what you have in mind. It seems to me that the set $A_{10}^n$, for $n\geq2$, contains all the natural numbers having less then $n$ digits plus the natural numbers having more than $n$ digits but having $0$ at the $n$-th place. So, $A_{10}^n$, for $n\geq2$ contains $1,10,100,1000,...$. Now this set is also contained in $A_1^1$, and the here is the choice with infinite intersection.

Comment: I am counting the digits from the right.  So (switching the index sets slightly) $A^n_i$ consists of those natural numbers with the digit $i$ in the $10^n$ place of the decimal expansion.

Comment: This last edit seems a bit extreme to me.  Wouldn't it make more sense to supply your own answer if you found mine confusing?

Answer (score 0):

I think Clinton Conley intended for the $n$th digit to be read from the right (one's digit is the first, ten's digit is the second, etc.).